# Convert ISO8601 to local time in a BASH variable

Tags: linux, bash, date, iso8601

I am plucking an ISO8601 variable "$sunrise" from an API.  Now I'd like to convert it to the local time. I have the $timeZone (America/Denver style) also as a variable.

An ISO8601 time stamp looks like this:  2019-11-09T11:36:14+00:00

I'd like a people friendly time in local time zone.  This will be sunrise.

I have tried every combination in a script I can think of like this:

`TZ="$timeZone" newSunrise=echo $date -d "$sunrise" +"%s"`

I can't get it to work.  Will someone please give me a hand?

Comment: edit your question to include examples of input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the timezone into the date reference, eg:

```
var="2019-11-09T11:36:14+00:00"
timeZone="America/Denver"
newsunrise=$(date -d"TZ=\"${timeZone}\" $var")
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on above solution, and generating result in the 'local time'

```
var="2019-11-09T11:36:14+00:00"
date -d"TZ=$(date +%Z) $var"
```

Calling `date +%Z` is required as the environment variable TZ is not always set. In those cases, the system-wide 'local time zone' (I believe /etc/timezone, but there could be additional logic).

Comment: I tried to fashion a line from your suggestion, but it fails too.  I'm sure what you've written is fine on the command line and it's my conversion to cron executable code causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

My code will be going in a program and assigning a variable.  I tried adapting both your suggestions, but neither worked as implemented by me.

`newSunrise=date -d"TZ=$(date +%Z) $sunrise"`

No data is stored in $newSunrise

Also, why did you escape out the quotes?  I'm just learning.

Comment: Bit late but what system were you on? Works for me copy/pasting on Win 11 Pro/WSL.

Answer (score 0):

`date` on Linux and `date` on macOS have differences. If you are on macOS, you could install the Linux version of `date` with `brew` and then use user4829160's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58776657/1702172) with a tiny change.

```
# Install the Linux version of date
brew install coreutils

# Use gdate instead of date
var="2019-11-09T11:36:14+00:00"
timeZone="America/Denver"
newsunrise=$(gdate -d"TZ=\"${timeZone}\" $var")
echo $newsunrise
```